# C++ polymorphism in mfc

Tags: c++, c, mfc

There is something i do not understand.

We overrided InitInstance okey but in CwinApp class have many virtual functions 
and create theApp object this is not pointer. This is object.

this is not fit a c++ polymorphism rule

Do i have a mistake ?

```
class CMyApp : public CWinApp {
public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance(void);//override
};
CMyApp theApp; //then create object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CMyApp theApp;
```

An object is said to be polymorphic if the static (i.e., during compilation) type is different than the dynamic (i.e., at runtime) type. In the above statement, `theApp` static and dynamic type is same which is `CMyApp`.

```
CWinApp *polyApp = new CMyApp();
```

In the above case, `polyApp` static type is `CWinApp` and the dynamic type is `CMyApp`.